# C# SharePoint 2010 Cannot create SiteCollection with new database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

we have a problem when we want to create a new SiteCollection with a new database on an existing sharepoint 2010 server.

We use the following command:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                {
                // Get the list of site collections for the web application 
                SPSiteCollection siteCollection = site.WebApplication.Sites;

                //Add the site collection                 
                siteCollection.Add(siteURL,
                title,
                description,
                lcid,
                template,
                @ownerLogin,
                ownerName,
                ownerEMail,
                secondaryLogin,
                secondaryName,
                secondaryEMail,
                databaseServer,
                databaseName,
                @databaseUser,
                databaseUserPassword);
                    }
            });
```

The lcid is "1033" and the database user is our **Farm Account** which also created the sharepoint 2010 server.
When the Add Method is executed we get the following error message: **Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at sqlservername. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.**

But the user has all rights on the server and also can connect to it, even from another server via Management Studio.

**Rights: dbcreator; public; securityadmin, sysadmin**

Creating a new SiteCollection without a new database is working.

Seperating the creation of the database and then creating the new SiteCollection in the new one also gives the same error when the database should be created.

**Edit: Added code**

We used the code from http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/31/creating-site-collections-in-specific-content-database/

```
contentDatabase = siteCollection.WebApplication.ContentDatabases.Add(
    serverName, 
    newDbName, 
    username, 
    password, 
    warningSiteCollectionNumber, 
    maximumSiteCollectionsNumber, 
    0);

contentDatabase.Update();
siteCollection.WebApplication.Update();
```

and then added the SiteCollection in the database:

```
newSite = contentDatabase.Sites.Add(
newSiteColectionUrl, 
siteCollectionTitle, 
siteCollectionDescription, 
1033, 
"MyTemplate#0", 
firstAdminLogin, 
firstAdminName, 
firstAdminEmail, 
secondAdminLogin, 
secondAdminName, 
secondAdminEmail);
```

But it doesn't even get to the SiteCollection creation.

We tested this command on two developer server with SharePoint and SQL Server installed on the same machine.

Because this error exists also when the server port ist not configured correctly, it's hard to search for my specific problem. So every help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Sebastian Neurohr

Comment: Could you also post the part of your code where you try to create the new content database?

Comment: Added the code in the post

Comment: have you tried prepending the username with the domain (i.e. `domain\username`)?

Comment: I tested with and without the domain in front. The Login in the SQL Server is domain\username